# How to unserialize a binary file into an object?

Tags: c++, boost

I used this method to serialize my object :

```
void save(Obj& obj) {
    ofstream os("obj.dat", ofstream::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(os, boost::archive::no_header);
    ar << boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&obj, sizeof(obj));
}
```

What would be my the code for my `Obj load(string fileName)` ?

Comment: What does [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) say? What have you tried? What problems do you have with your attempt? Do you have a [mcve] of your attempt to show us? And please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the same as what you had:

```
Obj load(std::string const& filename) {
    std::ifstream is(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(is, boost::archive::no_header);
    Obj obj;
    ar >> boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&obj, sizeof(obj));
    return obj;
}
```

Of course, this is **assuming** that your type is valid for use with `make_binary_object`: make sure that `Obj` is bitwise serializable (POD):

```
    static_assert(std::is_pod<Obj>::value, "Obj is not POD");
```

Also, reconsider `using namespace`: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Yeah that work, just tested it now. Thanks for the help. I was close to your solution but didn't know `make_binary_object` could be used in the opposite way.

Comment: `make_` does not "make" objects, it _`make`s_ an object _`binary` serializable_ using a [serialization wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html)